# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') in DetailView.js

Tags: reactjs, parameters, react-hooks

I have used match.params.id but recent update is not helping.

```
import { getPost } from '../../service/api';

const DetailView =({ match }) =>  {
  const classes = useStyle();
  const url = 'https://images.';
  const [post, setPost] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            let data = await getPost(match.params.id);
            console.log(data);
            setPost(data);
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);
```

***This is another calling by id code Inside another post-controller.js***

```
export const getPost = async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const post = await Post.findById(request.params.id);
        response.status(200).json(post);
    } catch (error) {
        response.status(500).json(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Share how you have wrapped `DetailView` inside react-router components. That will aid in debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `useParams` hook from `react-router-dom`:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const DetailView =() =>  {
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            let data = await getPost(id);
            ...
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother, thanx a lot , this code actually works.